# Can't read the file using std::wifstream C++

Tags: c++, file, std, wifstream

I try to read the file with specific extension .compressed. I created it using Fano encoding:

```cpp
std::ofstream out;
out.open(file_name + ".compressed", std::ios::out | std::ios::binary);
in.open(file_name, std::ios::in | std::ios::binary);
in >> std::noskipws;

if (!out) {
    out.close();

    in.close();
    return false;
}

wchar_t sym;
char buffer = 0;
int bit = 1;
while(in >> sym) {
    for (wchar_t b : fano_codes[sym]) {
        if (b == '1') buffer |= 0b00000001;
        if (bit == CHAR_BIT) {
            out << buffer;
            buffer = 0;
            bit = 1;
        }
        else {
            buffer <<= 1;
            bit++;
        }
    }

}
if (bit != 0) {
    for (; bit <= CHAR_BIT; bit++) {
        buffer <<= 1;
    }
    out << buffer;
}

out.close();
in.close();
```

So when I try to read this file it doesn't work.

```cpp
std::wifstream in;
in.imbue( std::locale(std::locale(), new std::codecvt_utf8<wchar_t>) );
in >> std::noskipws;
in.open(file_name, std::ios::binary | std::ios::in);

if (!in) {
    in.close();
    return false;
}

wchar_t sym;
std::wstring file_code;
while (in >> sym) { // this 'while' always is skipped
    file_code += sym;
}
in.close();
```

I used many `modes` (such as `std::ios::binary`) in `open()` function, checked all flags in stream and tried to use `get()` instead of `>>`, nothing worked and I don't know why.

Comment: Don't use `operator>>` and `operator<<` in `binary` mode, use `read()` and `write()` instead. Also, you wrote the file using a `char` stream, so why are you reading it with a `wchar_t` stream instead? And, is your file actually UTF-8 encoded? Why are you treating *compressed binary* data as if it were *textual* data?

Comment: @RemyLebeau I didn't know about read() and write(), where can I find more about read/wirite files in binary mode? I'm not sure, but don't we use binary mode to ignore the encoding?